# Error in algorithm to find the most repeating element in an array

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, frequency, function-definition

My task is to find the most repeating element in an array without sorting or hash-tables.

This is my pseudo-code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
  
int most_frequent(int *a, int n)
{
    int i, j, max_element, count;
    int maxcount = 0;

    for(i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        count = 1;
        for(j = i+1; j<n; j++)
        {
            if(a[j] == a[i])
            {
                count ++;
                if(count > maxcount)
                {
                    max_element = a[j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return max_element;
}
```

The problem is, that it doesn’t always work correctly, e.g. with the array `[1 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 7]`  the result will be `5`.

Comment: maxcount never changes

Answer (score 0):

In this if statement

```
            if(count > maxcount)
            {
                max_element = a[j];
            }
```

you forgot to change the variable maxcount

```
            if(count > maxcount)
            {
                maxcount = count;
                max_element = a[j];
            }
```

Moreover the if statement should be moved below the inner for loop.

```
for(i = 0; i<n; i++)
{
    count = 1;
    for(j = i+1; j<n; j++)
    {
        if(a[j] == a[i])
        {
            count ++;
        } 
    }

    if(count > maxcount)
    {
        maxcount = count;
        max_element = a[i];
    }

}
```

Pay attention to that if the user will pass to the function the value for the parameter n equal to 0 then the function will return an indeterminate value because the variable `max_element` is not initialized.

It will be much better to define the function such a way when it returns the index of the element with the most frequent occurrence something like  shown in the demonstration program below

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t most_frequent( const int *a, size_t n )
{
    size_t pos = 0;
    size_t max_count = 0;
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n - max_count; i++ )
    {
        size_t count = 1;
        for ( size_t j = i + 1; j < n; j++ )
        {
            if ( a[j] == a[i] ) ++count;
        }
        
        if ( max_count < count )
        {
            max_count = count;
            pos = i;
        }
    }
    
    return pos;
}

int main( void ) 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 7 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    size_t pos = most_frequent( a, N );
    
    printf( "The most frequent number is %d found at position %zu\n", 
            a[pos], pos );  

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
The most frequent number is 4 found at position 7
```